# Wi-Fi is active in monitored, but Wi-Fi Lamp Indicator isn't turned on

Tags: wireless, networking, laptop, indicator

Wi-Fi is active in screen monitored, but Wi-Fi Lamp Indicator in my laptop isn't turned on (should turned on). Can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the wifi is physically on and the led light is not then you could try resetting the wireless hardware by doing this in a Terminal window:

sudo rfkill list

...this will clear a soft block on the device and should bring it back

sudo rfkill unblock all

...this will clear any block in place for all devices found...